# I couldn't acces variable in child class

Tags: php

First, Thanks a lot

My problem is that i have Page which (indexStatic.php) have content variable return and affect  some head tags like include js files but when i start file is give this message:
I want to access variables which are displayControler.php in indexStatic.php

```
<b>Fatal error</b>:  Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'js doesn't exist in this class' in C:\webServer\htdocs\blabla\admin\AdminPanel\core\modelAbstract.php:25
Stack trace:
#0 C:\webServer\htdocs\blabla\admin\AdminPanel\static\indexStatic.php(2): ModelAbstract-&gt;__set('js', '&lt;script src=&quot;re...')
#1 C:\webServer\htdocs\blabla\admin\AdminPanel\core\tools.php(14): include('C:\webServer\ht...')
#2 C:\webServer\htdocs\blabla\admin\AdminPanel\core\displayControler.php(33): tools-&gt;includeFile('/static/indexSt...')
#3 C:\webServer\htdocs\blabla\admin\AdminPanel\core\displayControler.php(28): displayControler-&gt;getContentHtml('/static/indexSt...')
#4 C:\webServer\htdocs\blabla\admin\AdminPanel\core\displayControler.php(18): displayControler-&gt;setUrlTofunc(NULL)
#5 C:\webServer\htdocs\blabla\admin\AdminPanel\index.php(17): displayControler-&gt;showHtml()
#6 {main}
  thrown in <b>C:\webServer\htdocs\blabla\admin\AdminPanel\core\modelAbstract.php</b> on line <b>25</b><br />
```

indexStatic.php is included in displayControler.php lets see files :

indexStatic.php File :

```
    <?php
$this->js ='<script src="resources/scripts/editablegrid-2.0.1.js"></script> ';
$this->js .='<script src="resources/scripts/jquery-1.7.2.min.js" ></script>';
$this->js.='<script src="resources/scripts/demo.js" ></script>';
    return'<div class="content-box"><!-- Start Content Box -->
            <script type="text/javascript">
            window.onload = function() { 
                datagrid = new DatabaseGrid();
            }; 
        </script>       

            </div>';
    ?>
```

displayControler.php

```
class displayControler extends ModelAbstract
{
    protected $js;
    protected $tools;
    protected $title;
    protected $meta;
    protected $content='';
    protected $urls=array(
            'main'=>'static/aboutStatic.php'
            );

    public function __construct(){
        $this->setTitle(defaultVar::$static['title']);
    }

    public function showHtml(){
        $this->setUrlTofunc(@$_GET['cont']);
        include 'static/adminStatic.php';

    }

    public function setUrlTofunc($url){
        $this->tools=new tools();
        if(isset($url) and isset($this->urls[$url]) ){
            $this->getContentHtml($this->urls[$url]);
        }else{
            $this->getContentHtml(defaultVar::$static['filePath']);
        }

    }
    public function getContentHtml($url){
        $catch = $this->tools->includeFile($url);
        $this->setContent($catch);
    }
}
```

and modelAbstract.php is have  :

```
abstract class ModelAbstract{
    public function __call($name, $args){
        $methodPrefix = substr($name, 0,3);
        $methodProperty = strtolower($name[3]).substr($name,4);

        switch ($methodPrefix){
            case "set":
                if (count($args) == 1)
                    $this->__set($methodProperty,$args[0]);
                else
                    throw new \Exception("magic method only supports one argument");
                break;
            case "get":
                return $this->__get($methodProperty);
                break;
            default:
                throw new Exception("magic methods only supported for get and set");
        }
    }
    public function __set($name,$value){
        if (property_exists($this, $name))
        $this->$name = $value;
        else
            throw new \Exception("$name doesn't exist in this class");
    }
    public function __get($name){
        if (property_exists($this, $name))
            return $this->$name;
        else
            throw new \Exception("$name doesn't exist in this class");
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

The $js property is protected so you can not access it directly. You have magics in the Model class which make the getter and setter for your properties.

This means it will go through the magic call. Try using $this->setJs("") instead of $this->js = "".

Comment: @user2756017: then you should post your solution as an answer and accept it so that everything is nice and complete. Imagine someone with the same problem stumbles upon your question ;)

Comment: i dont have any solution.I did it another page but this is not working this case :S

Comment: @user2756017 I can't see where the index is included in the display controller.

Comment: if(isset($url) and isset($this->urls[$url]) ){
            $this->getContentHtml($this->urls[$url]);
        }else{